# problem installing "OpenAI PHP SDK" in PHP project

Tags: php, openai-api

I want to use OpenAI requests in my PHP project. So on the net I found I should install "OpenAI PHP SDK" with the `composer require openai/api` command.

However, composer gives me this error message: `Could not find a matching version of package openai/api. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (dev).`

From this I cannot understand what should I do. The package spelling should be ok. The version constraint (>8.1) also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are requiring the wrong package. There isn't any package named `openai/api`.
You can use [these](https://platform.openai.com/docs/libraries/community-libraries) packages to make requests to open ai.

Here's the list in case you don't want to login into openai:

1. [orhanerday/open-ai](https://packagist.org/packages/orhanerday/open-ai)
2. [tectalic/openai](https://github.com/tectalichq/public-openai-client-php)
3. [openai-php/client](https://github.com/openai-php/client)

For example, you can run this command too add the third package: `composer require openai-php/client`

Comment: Many thanks, you saved a desparate man.